# CSS different locally and bit different on heroku - Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have noticed that some styling is different on heroku and its different on my local environment. Basically on my local env i changed something aligned it properly but on heroku its the old version. I thought it was something that needed assets compilation again and used the below command but nothing.

`rake assets:precompile`

i have also cleared my cache on heroku

`heroku run rake tmp:cache:clear`

but it still does not work

any clues?

Comment: what about cache? its the first time i have this sort of error.

Comment: If you've changed something locally, then deployed (no matter if in the clouds, locally or wherever),but you still see the old version of the output, then the output is probably cached.

Comment: @AndreaLigios updated my answer. cache is not the culprit it seems.

Comment: I was meaning client-side caching (or proxy caching, but that's more rare). If you changed eg. a CSS, the CSS could be cached by the browser. Press CTRL+F5 or try with another browser to ensure it's not that.

Comment: If you have [setup your rails app correctly](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline) Heroku will automatically compile your assets after you push. If not you actually have to compile the assets locally - check them in and push. But I don't really recommend it since it adds tons of noise to the git changelog. Rails uses a figerprinting mechanism to bust the client cache - so you should not need to refresh your browser cache or clean out the cache on heroku.

Comment: @max seems Andrea Ligios was semi correct. In other browsers i can see the changes but even after clearing the chrome cache that was not the problem. A browser restart of chrome is what pulled the changes through. thats really weird. Even though i tried with Incognito i again saw the new changes. Maybe its a chrome plugin?

Comment: "Semi correct" ? It IS the cache, period :) just google how to clear Chrome cache (I use Firefox so I can't help, sorry).

Comment: @AndreaLigios oh well i wont argue you helped me enough ;p but Max said that cache should not be a problem because of the rails mechanism but anyhow thanks :)

Comment: Rails appends a digest to the filename for the assets file - so you don't actually need to remove the CSS file from the browser cache since the HTML link tag will actually point to another file after your push. That said if you for whatever reason are getting a stale HTML response the browser will still download the old version of the asset. This happens if you have fragment caching or a reverse proxy. Can't say that it has really happened to me on heroku.

Comment: @max  well i do not have fragment caching and i have no idea what reverse proxy is so i do not think i have any of those. thanks for the help thought!